# index and tag switching position

Tags: caching, mips

Let us consider the alternative {Index, Tag, Offset}. The usage and the size of each of the field remain the same, e.g. index is used to locate a block in cache, and its bit-length is still determined by the number of cache blocks. The only difference is that we now uses the MSB bits for index, the middle portion for tag, and the last portion for offset.

What do you think is the shortcoming of this scheme?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work — and if the cache is fully associative this won't matter (as there is no index, its all tag), but if the associativity is limited it will make (far) less effective use of the cache memory.  Why?

Consider an object, that is sufficiently large to cross a cache block boundary.

When accessing the object, the address of some fields vs. the other fields will not be in the same cache block.  How will the cache behave?

When the `index` is in the middle, then the cache block/line index will change, allowing the cache to store different nearby entities even with limited associativity.

When the `index` is at the beginning (most significant bytes), the tag will have changed between these two addresses, but the index will be the same — thus, there will be an collision at the index, which will use up one of the ways of the set-associativity.  If the cache were direct mapped (i.e. 1-way set associative), it could thrash badly on repeated access to the same object.

Let's pretend that we have 12-bit address space, and the index, tag, and offset are each 4 bits.

Let's consider an object of four 32-bit integer fields, and that the object is at location 0x248 so that two integer fields, a, b, are at 0x248 and 0x24c and two other integer fields, c, d, are at 0x250 and 0x254.

Consider what happens when we access either a or b followed by c or d followed by a or b again.

If the tag is the high order hex digit, then the cache index (in the middle) goes from `4` to `5`, meaning that even in an direct mapped cache both the a&b fields and the c&d fields can be in the cache at the same time.

For the same access pattern, if the tag is the middle hex digit and the index the high hex digit, then the cache index doesn't change — it stays at `2`.  Thus, on a 1-way set associative cache, accessing fields a or b followed by c or d will evict the a&b fields, which will result in a miss if/when a or b are accessed later.

So, it really depends on access patterns, but one thing that makes a cache really effective is when the program accesses either something it accessed before or something in the same block as it accessed before.  This happens as we manipulate individual objects, and as we allocate objects that end up being adjacent, and as we repeat accesses to an array (e.g. 2nd loop over an array).

If the `index` is in the middle, we get more variation as we use different addresses of within some block or chunk or area of memory — in our 12-bit address space example, the index changes every 16 bytes, and adjacent block of 16 bytes can be stored in the cache.

But if the `index` is at the beginning we need to consume more memory before we get to a different `index` — the index changes only every 256 bytes, so two adjacent 16-byte blocks will often have collisions.

Our programs and compilers are generally written assuming locality is favored by the cache — and this means that the index should be in the middle and the tag in the high position.

Both tag/index position options offer good locality for addresses in the same block, but one favors adjacent addresses in different blocks more than the other.